# Whats happens with GET Video Adwords Campaigns

Tags: google-ads-api

recently i started a project to get campaigns from google adwords api and make analytics reports about that info.

I have that issue:

I launch this piece of code to get all campaigns:

```
public function testGetCampaigns()
{
    $user = new \AdWordsUser();
    $user->LogAll();

    $campaignService = $user->GetService('CampaignService', 'v201603');

    // Create selector.go
    $selector = new \Selector();
    $selector->fields = array('Id', 'Name');
    $selector->ordering[] = new \OrderBy('Name', 'ASCENDING');

    // Create paging controls.
    $selector->paging = new \Paging(0, \AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);

    do {
        $page = $campaignService->get($selector);
        if (isset($page->entries)) {
            foreach ($page->entries as $campaign) {
                printf("Campaign with name '%s' and ID '%s' was found.\n",
                $campaign->name, $campaign->id);
            }
        } else {
            print "No campaigns were found.\n";
        }

        $selector->paging->startIndex += \AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE;
    } while ($page->totalNumEntries > $selector->paging->startIndex);

}
```

But the result is not the two campaigns that i created, is just only one.

I have to say that the one that the api dont give to me, is a Video Campaigns, and not a search campaign.

RESULT OF THE CODE:

1 / 1 (100%)Campaign with name 'Testingalot' and ID '469071928' was found.

---

[image: Failure]

Comment: Can it be a problem with the paging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct because CampaignService does not show video campaigns in listings. See e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/SH7lk_y4GTw

Comment: I fixed the problem long time ago, Yes, google sucks and they dont have any way to manipulate video campaign in adwords. Thx