# Why Can't I Get Google Adwords Video Campaigns?

Tags: php, api, get, google-ads-api

There seems to be an issue for getting all Adwords campaigns. When I currently try to retrieve all campaigns, I don't get the video campaigns. My understanding through the documentation was that it shouldn't be this much work. Another SO user had the similar problem [Whats happens with GET Video Adwords Campaigns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497079/whats-happens-with-get-video-adwords-campaigns)

Is this a Google Adwords error, deprecation error, or something that I messed up on my end?

```
require_once('Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsUser.php');

$oauth2Info = array('client_id' => $client_id, 'client_secret' => $client_secret, 'access_token' => $access_token);

$user = new AdWordsUser();
$user->SetDeveloperToken($developer_token);
$user->SetOAuth2Info($oauth2Info);

$customerService = $user->GetService('CustomerService', 'v201509');
$customer = $customerService->get();

$user->SetClientCustomerId($customer->customerId);

$campaignService = $user->GetService('CampaignService', 'v201509');

$selector = new Selector();
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'Name');
$selector->ordering[] = new OrderBy('Name', 'ASCENDING');
$selector->paging = new Paging(0, 500);
$page = $campaignService->get($selector);
```

The page value only contains non-video campaigns. I'm in the process of upgrading API, so maybe it can't get videos for API version v201509?

Comment: *My crystal ball says....* There is no way we could possibly know if you messed something up because you have not shown us anything to judge that question by.

Comment: I didn't do anything special or different than the past user which I posted a link to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Adwords API does not currently support video campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect some data thanks to the video performance report : https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/video-performance-report.

This is the only data you can get on TrueView (video Adwords) through the API.